# Django 1.6 doesn't see comments form

Tags: python, django, comments

I use the standard Django comments framework. I don't have errors, but don't see comments form. Why?

Detail post template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head_title %}{{ post_detail.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}{{ post_detail.title }}{% endblock %}
{% load comments %}
{% block content %}
{{ post_detail.body }}
{% endblock %}

{% block comments %}
{% for post in post_detail %}
{% get_comment_list for post as comment_list %}
{% render_comment_form for post %}
{% for comment in comment_list %}
{{ comment.comment }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Views:

```
def view_post(request, slug):
post_detail = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
return render_to_response('view_post.html', {
    'post_detail': post_detail
})
```

Comment: Do you have any comment objects? `{% render_comment_form for post %}` should probably be outside the `{% for comment in comment_list %}` loop.

Comment: i edit original message